# Jquery AutoComplete : How to get the selected items id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have an auto complete field which is working perfectly, and fetch the data from the database. When user selects a result from the response, i want to save the id of the selected item in a hidden field.

Here is the code I'm using for autocomplete

```
 $jQNetbmis("input#txt_client_name").autocomplete("autosuggest_clientmaster.php", {
        width: 160,
        mustMatch: true,
        selectFirst:false,
        formatResult: function(row) {
            var resStr = row.toString();
            temp = resStr.substring(0,resStr.indexOf("+"));
            return temp;
        },
        formatItem: function(row, i, max) {
            var resStr = row.toString();
            var temp = resStr.substring(0,resStr.indexOf("+"));
            return temp;
        }
     });
```

Following is the response that i get i press n

```
name 1+50
Name 2+85
Name 3+86
Name 4+98
Name 5 +103
```

If the user selects name 1 i want to save 50 in to the hidden field .

I'm using Autocomplete - jQuery plugin 1.0.2

Krishnik

Comment: I'm not understanding the part about "Following is the response that i get i press n" Can you be more clear or provide more info? If you know what you want to put into the hidden field, then why can't you? `$('input#hidden-field').attr('value', yourNumberHere);`

Comment: @matthewpavkov Its the response from the server that i get when i press letter 'n' in the keyboard. It fetch names staring with n along with their ids. The server sends back the response in the following form 'Title + id'.  formatItem will strip +id part from the result and only displays the title. So if the user selects name 2 i want to get the id 85 and save it in a hidden field so that i can use it later. Sorry for confusing you .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`result`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/result) handler to do this. An example of how you might wish to accomplish this is:

```
$('input#txt_client_name').result(function(event, data){
    $('input#hidden_field').val(data.substring(data.indexOf('+') + 1));
});
```

The handler is ran every time the user selects an item. As an aside, you might want to use the jQuery UI Autocomplete instead of this plugin, which is deprecated in favor of that.

Comment: Thank you Yi Jiang I had to use data[0] instead of data.indexOf. And Made few changes.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI has an excellent autocomplete widget which is pretty well documented: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/. Your case is also there so go through examples.

Comment: He's not actually using the jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin - the current version for that is 1.8.x, and the functions used in the code he gave do not exist in jQuery UI Autocomplete. He's using this plugin: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know the autocomplete you're using but the problem doesn't seem to come from it.

Just concatenate the id with the existing value of the hidden field :

```
$jQNetbmis("input#txt_client_name").autocomplete("autosuggest_clientmaster.php", {
    width: 160,
    mustMatch: true,
    selectFirst:false,
    formatResult: function(row) {
        var resStr = row.toString();
        //temp = resStr.substring(0,resStr.indexOf("+"));
        var temp = resStr.split('+');
        $('input#hidden_field').val($('input#hidden_field').val()+'+'+temp[1]);
        return temp[0];
    },
    formatItem: function(row, i, max) {
        var resStr = row.toString();
        var temp = resStr.substring(0,resStr.indexOf("+"));
        return temp;
    }
 });
```

Comment: formatResult,formatItem both will be called for every item in restult set. So I'm will get only the last values id every time